# how to pass data between 2 unrelated components by using subjects in angular?

Tags: angular, rxjs-observables

Here I'm trying to pass an id from component1 to my service and I'm using the subject to
emit that id inside the service. I'm trying to subscribe to that subject from component2
to get the id. But I'm not able to get the id.

**component1**

```
    export class ContestUploadButtonComponent implements OnInit {
            contestId:any
            ngOnInit(): void {
            this.contestId = this.contest
            this.frontEnd.contestData(this.contestId)
              }
       

      }
```

**service**

```
    @Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root'
    })
    export class FrontendService {
    
      constructor() { }
    
      contest = new Subject<string>()
    
      contestData(data:string){
         this.contest.next(data)
      }
    
      dialogData():Observable<string>{
        return this.contest.asObservable()
      }
    }
```

**component 2**

```
    export class ContestUploadDialogComponent implements OnInit {
    
      file:File|any
      filePath!:string;
      contestId:string=""
    
      constructor(private backEnd : BackendService,private frontEnd:FrontendService) { }
    
      ngOnInit(): void {
        this.frontEnd.dialogData().subscribe((contestId)=>{
          console.log(contestId);
          this.contestId = contestId
    
        })
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try to change your `Subject` to `ReplaySubject(1)` -> then your new subscription should get last emitted data from Observable

**1** in example meat count of last emitted data to Observable

Comment: ReplaySubject is working perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Small addition to @gzn,
it may happen due to order in which ngOnInit methods are called, so you should save last emitted value and give it to a new subscribers. In this case you can try using `BehaviouralSubject` or `ReplaySubject(1)` as was already told

Comment: ReplaySubject works perfectly